# Wrong barcode being scanned into a web form in Chrome?

Tags: barcode-scanner

For some reason, abour 50% of the time, if I scan a standard book ISBN barcode into Chrome, it will read 9781782941972 as 9780008134372?!

We have a web based data management system with a web form that requires a barcode. It will then return the book's data to another div. It's worked for years but over the past few months it's started reading the wrong barcodes.

The html looks like this...

```
<form id="location_lookup" name="location_lookup" method="get" style="float:left;">
          <div style="float:left;clear:left;margin-bottom:10px;">
              <label for="isbn13">Barcode/Product Code :</label>
              <input id="isbn13" name="isbn13" type="text" value="" />
              <input id="isbn13" name="function" type="hidden" value="lookupProduct" />
          </div>
          <div style="float:left;clear:left;">
              <input type="submit" value="Send" class="bigbutton" />
              <input type="reset" value="Clear" id="formReset" class="bigbutton"/>
          </div>
        </form>
```

so the input with id isbn13 has a 13-digit number dumped into it by a simple barcode scanner. The barcode scanner is set to enter a CR after the barcode is dumped (and hence submit the form). Then this runs...

```
$("#location_lookup").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

        var isbn13 = $("input[name='isbn13']").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "location_functions.php",
            type: "get",
            data: values,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                }
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(values){

                //does more stuff...
```

It's a boring, perfectly normal barcode reader that's being scanned into a basic PHP web input. I've tried swapping over the scanners but it still seems to happen. I've also tried disabling the anti-virus but again, it still happens!

I just don't get what's happening!

Comment: can you post a minimal code snippet for us to have a look at?

Comment: there's a snippet

Comment: you've got 2 `isbn13` IDs there, I doubt that's causing the problem you're talking about but you'll want to change that if that's in your application and not just this snippet.

Comment: I have no idea what a "simple barcode scanner" is or how it would dump data into a web page. If you can see the value in `isbn13` on the page is wrong before you even submit the form then it must be to do with the API or whatever it is that reads the barcode and sends it to your webpage

Comment: Ok, I'll simplify the code and update the question if it repeats itself. I have a feeling it could be to do with the browser interpreting a single barcode scan (and its subsequent carriage return) poorly and it's conflicting with its own autocomplete. Anyway, I'll get back to you @Pete

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Experiencing something similar. Have just plain text boxes and on a couple forms the field meant for a barcode scan gets the wrong text entered when scanned some times.  Users have tried barcoding the same barcode into non-barcode fields and gets the correct value. This doesnt happen in Edge. Just Chrome. No JavaScript attached to these fields.

Comment: Yes @KeithFranklin, I did. It turned out the browser was auto-completing the field and submitting it before the barcode reader could complete the field. By adding autocomplete="off" to the text input the problem went away :)